# How can I vertically center a div inside a div with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying this:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

Ignoring the style, I just want to vertically center "Pasión por el vestuario".

This is my HTML code (I'm using Bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-12 " id="pasion-div">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS used in that sole container:

```
#pasion-div{
    background-image: url("media/imagen-fondo-menu.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 13px;
}

#pasion-texto{
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    /*width: 400px;*/
}
```

I've tried this:

```
.vertical-align {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But it is just moving it to the upper left.

I'm thinking there's some conflict between some elements, or maybe the divs aren't well ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the slider on full width at all times, you can drop the col-sm-12 class(as with it, the width will always be 100% in all resolutions) and add these styles in addition to yours:

```
#pasion-div{
    background-image: url("media/imagen-fondo-menu.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 13px;

    /* add these */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#pasion-div > div {    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

display: table-cell works in IE8 (including) and up.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use transforms to accomplish this. I have set up a quick example for you here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hrmjd6ca/

check out caniuse for browser support:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background:#c4c4c4;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 20%;
}

.centre-aligned {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container centre-aligned">
    <div class="label">Some text</div>
    <div class="label">hello, world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers then you could use flexbox for this:

CSS

```
.flex-row {display:flex;}

#pasion-div {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    ...
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 " id="pasion-div">
            <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/mbrowne/pen/kXvQyr

Or if you need wider browser support then you can use `display:table` as @MajeStic suggested.